# Is the question "How to evaluate your manager/boss?" on topic?

Tags: discussion

I would like to get tips on how I could evaluate my manager or my boss without being unjust.

So, is this question on topic here?

Comment: The upvote is about the question about your question, not the "How would you evaluate your manager" question.  It's a horrible question as it stands now, but with more information about your specific experience, it can be greatly improved.  Please take advantage of all of that wonderful space they give you in the question box, this isn't Twitter. :)

Answer (score 5):

I would say that this question is off-topic here.

I believe it would be welcome at [programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Could you open this question at their [meta SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/) and let us know their feedback?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I've put there too.

Comment: I have found the question on programmers SE, but it looks like they kick the ball again: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/is-the-question-how-to-evaluate-your-manager-boss-on-topic

Comment: +1 - Check out [Anna Lear's answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/is-the-question-how-to-evaluate-your-manager-boss-on-topic/1184#1184). She says it's off topic because it's too broad.  This question could apply to an accountant, and that's why Anna rejected it.  If we apply that same logic here, we reject it because it's not specifically about project management.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's more vague than off topic.  There are way too many questions here that could simply be solved on the first page of Google with the right search keywords.

We need more questions that are specific examples of problems that you face, as defined in the [FAQ](https://pm.stackexchange.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

That's not to say "How do you evaluate your boss" is a bad question if more specifics were given.  For instance, if your boss was hard to talk to and you needed advice on whether or not certain criteria were applicable to the scenario, and you wanted to know if the criteria was measurable and how to do so, then that might be a better question.

I picture the questions here working a lot like those on Programmers SE.  They should be thoughtful questions, based on experiences, and have answers that are more than a single, hit-and-run sentence.

[Here are some great example questions from Programmers SE that, with some work, would fit really well on this site!](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/is-the-question-how-to-evaluate-your-manager-boss-on-topic/1185#1185)

Comment: From my experience on SU & SO, they also have thousands of questions that could be answered on 5 seconds on google. As I'm sure Ivo Flipse could attest to, there are hundreds of questions asking how to I convert jpg to png? How do I convert jpg to gif?  They tend to be vague (i.e. no mention of OS until after you answer the question) and similar to other questions, but just different enough that it's hard to justify closing them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else here that this question is vague, but I think that misses the point. This question is trying to find out if a particular question is on-topic or not, not if it's a candidate for the best PM question Hall of Fame.

I can accept [Mark's answer](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-the-question-how-to-evaluate-your-manager-boss-on-topic/50#50) - it's on topic because it's about the relationship between a manager and a team member, but to me this is more of an HR question than a PM question.  That said, HR Management falls withing the sphere of project management.

If this site is intended to encompass the entire craft of project management, then what topics are out of bounds?  Even after the commit phase, we haven't really defined that as well as we should.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it would be on-topic here since it deals with the relationship between a team member and a manager.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote.  Nothing personal, but there are way too many one liner questions on here so far that don't meet guidelines in the FAQ.  I'll upvote your answer if you edit it and add that it could be on topic **if** the OP describes his/her experience or asks a more specific question that isn't so broad.  Let's work together to make this a success!

Comment: @jmort253 -really? you're holding my answer hostage until it says what you want it to say?  ---in terms of why I believe its on-topic is because he gave the specific situation, just in not so many words e.g. what are objective ways to rate a manager's performance (with emphasis on objective, so personal feelings don't get in the way).  The answer would speak to specific performance metrics that a manager could be measured on.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate more in your answer or give more information about why this is a good question.  I suspect you have a pretty strong, well-thought out, passionate opinion, but your actual documented answer is still a vague, one-liner that I don't currently agree with.  Convince me why this is a good question based on what the founders intended this site to be.  Find something in the FAQ that I missed.  Locate some evidence to convince me otherwise that this question in it's current form fits the guidelines.

Comment: @jmort253 Ha ha. It was fun reading your comments. You are both awesome and so assertive! I wish I could talk like this.